# React Material-UI How can I add a checkbox which is separate from table row click

Tags: javascript, reactjs, checkbox, material-ui, material-table

I want to differentiate between a checkbox click and a row click.

For example, I want this behavior, when I click the checkbox, only the checkbox is checked and when I click the row, only the row is selected but the checkbox is not selected. How can I achieve this?

Below is my code

```
handleClick = (row) => {
var self = this;
var currentlist = self.state.routelist;

let newarray = [...this.state.routelist];

if (newarray[row].isselected === true) {
  newarray[row].isselected = false;
} else if (newarray[row].isselected === false) {
  newarray[row].isselected = true;
}

self.setstate({ routelist: newarray });

if (!isnan(row)) 
{
    var pos = 
    {
      routeid: currentlist[row].routeid,
      isvisible: currentlist[row].isselected
    };

    var param = {
      receiver: "event_map",
      command: "show_route",
      data: pos
    };

    //console.log("show_route: " + param.data.routeid + " visible: " + param.data.isvisible);
    this.msgdispatcher.triggermessagedispatcher(param);

    //zoom to route
    if (currentlist[row].routeid != null ||currentlist[row].routeid != undefined) 
    {
      var param = {
        receiver: "event_map",
        command: "zoom_to_route",
        data: currentlist[row].routeid
      };

      //console.log("zoom_to_route: routeid=" + param.data);
      this.msgdispatcher.triggermessagedispatcher(param);
    }
}
}
```

And here is the render method

```
render() {
return (
  <div style={{ padding: "0px" }}>
    <div style={{ padding: "0px" }}>
    <Table  
        onCellClick={this.handleClick}
        height={window.innerHeight}
        multiSelectable={this.state.multiSelectable}
        selectable={this.state.selectable}
      >
        <TableBody 
          displayRowCheckbox={this.state.displayRowCheckbox}
          showRowHover={this.state.showRowHover}
          deselectOnClickaway={this.state.deselectOnClickaway}
          >
          {this.state.routeList.map((row, index) => (
            <TableRow
              key={index}
              style={{ backgroundColor: row.DistressColor }}
              selected={this.state.routeList[index].isSelected}
            >
              <TableRowColumn style={{ padding: "0px" }}>
                <ListItem
                  style={{ height: "80px" }}
                  primaryText={row.Description}
                  secondaryText={
                    <div>
                      <div>
                        {"Direction : " + row.EntryDirection + " > " + row.ExitDirection}
                      </div>
                      <div>{"Distance (meter) : " + row.Distance}</div>
                    </div>
                  }
                  secondaryTextLines={5}
                />
              </TableRowColumn>
            </TableRow>
          ))}
        </TableBody>
      </Table>
      <hr />
    </div>
  </div>
);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Method_#1

You can use the child component of `ListItem`: **ListItemSecondaryAction**

It provides the additional action element where you can use to place your buttons, which would not be affected by the main `ListItem` click event.

You can pass that as props named **children** to `ListItem`, but notice:

> If a ListItemSecondaryAction is used it must be the last child.

---

Refer:

- API of [ListItem](https://material-ui.com/api/list-item/#import)
- API of [ListItemSecondaryAction](https://material-ui.com/api/list-item-secondary-action/)
- documentation of the usage [demo](https://material-ui.com/components/lists/#checkbox)

---

Sample source:

```
<ListItem alignItems="flex-start" className={classes.listUnit} key={book.isbn}>
  <ListItemAvatar>
    <Avatar alt="Remy Sharp" src={url} />
  </ListItemAvatar>
  <ListItemText
    primary={book.title}
    secondary={
      <>...</>
    }
  />
  <ListItemSecondaryAction>
    <Tooltip title="Add to order" aria-label="add">
      <IconButton edge="end" aria-label="comments">
        <AddIcon />
      </IconButton>
    </Tooltip>
  </ListItemSecondaryAction>
</ListItem>;
```

- Try it online: [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/github/ibarapascal/netbooks/tree/master/?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark)

---

#### Method_#2

If you don't want to use Material-UI internal solution.

You can simply add some customized processes in your parent event handler callback.

Use **stopPropagation()** to prevent child event, then add a separate click event on child would work.

> The `stopPropagation()` method of the Event interface prevents further propagation of the current event in the capturing and bubbling phases.

```
event.stopPropagation();
```

Comment: Do you mean, that I should place my checkbox inside the ListItemSecondaryAction? Because right now, the checkboxes are generated by the table, with this option displayRowCheckbox={true}

Comment: @Amir Yes, that the solution I provide. Kindly try the online demo, you can add some console.log with the handler function, to see if it's been fired or not.

Comment: Thank you, I used method one